# How can I set up a CDC replication from AWS RDS PostgreSQL to Kafka using Pglogical?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, logical-replication, pglogical

Is it possible to setup replication from PostgreSQL to Kafka using PGlogical?
Currently we are using attunity as our replication tool which has been causing issues on our instances.
We are using RDS PostgreSQL.

Comment: That tool doesn't mention anything about kafka. What's wrong with Debezium?

Comment: @OneCricketeer Yes, I did read about Debezium. Not able to find steps involved in it. specifically for AWS RDS/Aurora instances.

Comment: Is that so? https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/1.0/connectors/postgresql.html#amazon-rds